Trying to bound the growth rate of the Dirichlet Inverse of $f(n) = e^{-m n}$.
I conjecture and suspect that for the arithmetic function $f(n) = e^{-m n}$, for $m$ a constant $\geq \ln(2)$, that $$|f^{-1}(n)| \leq C_1 e^{-m n C_2}$$, where $C_1 = O(m n^k)$, for some $k > 0$, and $C_2 \in (0, 1]$.
However, I have been trying and unsuccessful to prove this for a while. The best I have been able to show is that:
For $d_{\text{min}} = \displaystyle{\min_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$, $d_{\text{max}} = \displaystyle{\max_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$, and $\xi \in ( \frac{1}{\text{d_max}} - \frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{\text{d_min}})$.
$$|f^{-1}(n)|  \leq  \begin{cases}
     e^{-m(n-2)}, & \text{if $n$ is prime }\\
     e^{-m(n-2)} + \frac{e^{m}}{e^m - 1}(m(\text{d_max} + 1 - \text{d_min} ) e^{-mn \xi} - (n - \sigma_0(n)) \exp(-m \dfrac{{n \choose 2} - (\sigma_1(n) - n))}{n - \sigma_0(n)}))   ,& \text{else }\\
\end{cases} $$. (Proposition 2)
Here is the derivation:
Proposition 1:  For $m \geq \ln(2)$,  $f(k) = e^{-mk}$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$,
$|f^{-1}(k)| \leq 1$ for all $k \geq 2$.
We proceed by induction.
Proof:
Since, $f^{-1}(1) = e^{m}$, we have that $|f^{-1}(2)| = | \dfrac{f(2) f^{-1}(1)}{f(1)}| = |e^{-2m} e^{2m}| = 1 $,  establishing the base case.
Now suppose this holds for all $2 < j \leq n-1$. Then,
$|f^{-1}(n)| = |-f^{-1}(1) \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d < n}}} f\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right) f^{-1}(d)|   = |e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d < n}}} f\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right) f^{-1}(d)| \leq e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d < n}}} |f\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)| | f^{-1}(d)| $
$ = e^{2m}|f(n)| + e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} |f\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)| |f^{-1}(d)| = e^{-m(n-2)} + e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} |f^{-1}(d)|$
$\leq e^{-m(n-2)} + e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} $  (by our Inductive assumption),
$ < e^{-m(n-2)} + e^{m}\displaystyle{\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}} e^{-m k} = \frac{1 + e^{-m(n-2)}(e^{m}-2)}{e^{m}-1}  \leq  \frac{1 + e^{-m}(e^{m}-2)}{e^{m}-1}$  (since $n \geq 3$),
 
$ =  2 e^{-m} \leq 1$, $m \geq \ln(2) $ .
Thus, $|f^{-1}(n)| \leq 1$, completing the inductive proof.
Proposition 2:  For $m \geq \ln(2)$,  $f(k) = e^{-mk}$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $d_{\text{min}} = \displaystyle{\min_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$, $d_{\text{max}} = \displaystyle{\max_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$, and $\xi \in ( \frac{1}{\text{d_max}} - \frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{\text{d_min}})$,
|$f^{-1}(n)|  \leq  \begin{cases}
     e^{-m(n-2)}, & \text{if $n$ is prime }\\
     e^{-m(n-2)} + \frac{e^{m}}{e^m - 1}(m(\text{d_max} + 1 - \text{d_min} ) e^{-mn \xi} - (n - \sigma_0(n)) \exp(-m \dfrac{{n \choose 2} - (\sigma_1(n) - n))}{n - \sigma_0(n)}))   ,& \text{else }\\
\end{cases} $
Proof:
For $n$ prime, we have that $|f^{-1}(n)| = e^{-m(n-2)}$.
For $n$ composite:
$|f^{-1}(n)|  \leq e^{-m(n-2)} +e^{m}|\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} f^{-1}(d)| \leq e^{-m(n-2)} + e^{m}\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} |f^{-1}(d)| $
$\leq e^{-m(n-2)} + e^{m}\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} $        (by Proposition 1).
And let $d_{\text{min}} = \displaystyle{\min_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$, $d_{\text{max}} = \displaystyle{\max_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d$.
Then
$\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=d_{\text{min}}}^{d_{\text{max}}}} e^{-m d} -  \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-md} = \dfrac{e^{-m(d_{\text{min}} - 1 )} - e^{-m d_{\text{max}} }}{e^{m} - 1}  - \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-md} $ .
By Jensen's inequality,
$-\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-md} \leq -(\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} 1) \exp(-m \frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} d }{\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d \nmid n \\ 1 < d < n}}} 1}) = -(n - \sigma_0(n)) \exp(-m \dfrac{{n \choose 2} - (\sigma_1(n) - n))}{n - \sigma_0(n)})$.
So,
$\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ 1 < d < n}}} e^{-m \frac{n}{d}} \leq \dfrac{e^{-m(d_{\text{min}} - 1 )} - e^{-m d_{\text{max}} }}{e^{m} - 1} -(n - \sigma_0(n)) \exp(-m \dfrac{{n \choose 2} - (\sigma_1(n) - n))}{n - \sigma_0(n)}) $
And since $\frac{n}{\text{d_min}} = \text{d_max}$,
$e^{-m(d_{\text{min}} - 1 )} - e^{-m d_{\text{max}} } =e^{-mn(\frac{1}{\text{d_max}} - \frac{1}{n} )} - e^{-m n \frac{1}{\text{d_min}} } = m(\text{d_max} + 1 - \text{d_min} ) e^{-mn \xi}$
for some $\xi \in ( \frac{1}{\text{d_max}} - \frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{\text{d_min}})$,
by the mean value theorem.
In total, we are left with:
$$|f^{-1}(n)|  \leq e^{-m(n-2)} + \frac{e^{m}}{e^m - 1}(m(\text{d_max} + 1 - \text{d_min} ) e^{-mn \xi} - (n - \sigma_0(n)) \exp(-m \dfrac{{n \choose 2} - (\sigma_1(n) - n))}{n - \sigma_0(n)}))$$,
for some $\xi \in ( \frac{1}{\text{d_max}} - \frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{\text{d_min}})$.
I don't know if there's much left to pursue in this direction, as there is no way to verify that the $\xi$ factor is independent of $n$, and hence would not qualify as a constant factor of $mn$ in the exponent. Would anyone have any suggestions or maybe a different approach that they think would be more fruitful?
